# How to migrate Spreedly data to stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, spreedly

I try to export spreedly data like credit cards and customers to stripe but I'm not sure what data i need to use to create a stripe token. I'm using ruby on rails, this is an example of the retriaved data from the spreedly api

Someone know what data I need to use to generate the stripe token?

```
{  
  customer=>{  
    :email=> "example@gmail.com",
    :token=> "SsEFMRoEInyZvZasdfasdJHG78",
    :credit_card=>{  
      :address_city=> "Distrito Federal",
      :address_line1=> "Colima 436 int 104",
      :address_state=> "DIF",
      :address_zip=> "06700",
      :country=> "MX",
      :cvc_check=> "",
      :exp_month=> "11",
      :exp_year=> "2019",
      :fingerprint=> "d80c788asdfasdJHG780511a2f67dc2F83",
      :last4=> "1111",
      :name=> "User",
      :tokenization_method=> "S780511a2f67dc2F83tsic788as"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export all your cards from Spreedly to Stripe, the best solution is likely to contact them directly. They have a team that can export card details to other processors like Stripe without you having to write code or handling sensitive data. Stripe would then be able to import all customers and cards in your Stripe account which they document here: https://stripe.com/docs/security/data-migrations/imports

Another approach would be to use Spreedly's API. This is something they document here: https://docs.spreedly.com/guides/exporting/#performing-the-export